# Gulp Won't Compile SASS unless style.scss is edited

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm using Gulp on a WordPress website, and I have it setup using WPGulp. It's working somewhat, except I'm running into a couple issues. Browsersync isn't happening at all. And it won't compile any SASS unless I also save or edit the style.scss file.

My folder structure for sass files is like this:

theme-name/assets/css (that's the css destination folder)
theme-name/assets/sass/style.scss (all the partials are imported into this file)

Partials are structured like this: 
theme-name/assets/sass/base/typography/_headings.scss

_headings.scss would be imported into base, which would be imported into style.scss

Here's my wpgulp.config.js file:

```
 /**
 * WPGulp Configuration File
 *
 * 1. Edit the variables as per your project requirements.
 * 2. In paths you can add <<glob or array of globs>>.
 *
 * @package WPGulp
 */

module.exports = {

// Project options.
projectURL: 'localhost:8888/s2breakthrough', // Local project URL of your already running WordPress site. Could be something like wpgulp.local or localhost:3000 depending upon your local WordPress setup.
productURL: './', // Theme/Plugin URL. Leave it like it is, since our gulpfile.js lives in the root folder.
browserAutoOpen: true,
injectChanges: true,

// Style options.
styleSRC: './assets/sass/*', // Path to main .scss file.
styleDestination: './assets/css/', // Path to place the compiled CSS file. Default set to root folder.
outputStyle: 'compact', // Available options → 'compact' or 'compressed' or 'nested' or 'expanded'
errLogToConsole: true,
precision: 10,

// JS Vendor options.
jsVendorSRC: './assets/js/vendor/*.js', // Path to JS vendor folder.
jsVendorDestination: './assets/js/', // Path to place the compiled JS vendors file.
jsVendorFile: 'vendor', // Compiled JS vendors file name. Default set to vendors i.e. vendors.js.

// JS Custom options.
jsCustomSRC: './assets/js/custom/*.js', // Path to JS custom scripts folder.
jsCustomDestination: './assets/js/', // Path to place the compiled JS custom scripts file.
jsCustomFile: 'custom', // Compiled JS custom file name. Default set to custom i.e. custom.js.

// Images options.
imgSRC: './assets/img/raw/**/*', // Source folder of images which should be optimized and watched. You can also specify types e.g. raw/**.{png,jpg,gif} in the glob.
imgDST: './assets/img/', // Destination folder of optimized images. Must be different from the imagesSRC folder.

// Watch files paths.
watchStyles: './assets/sass/*', // Path to all *.scss files inside css folder and inside them.
watchJsVendor: './assets/js/vendor/*.js', // Path to all vendor JS files.
watchJsCustom: './assets/js/custom/*.js', // Path to all custom JS files.
watchPhp: './**/*.php', // Path to all PHP files.

// Translation options.
textDomain: 'WPGULP', // Your textdomain here.
translationFile: 'WPGULP.pot', // Name of the translation file.
translationDestination: './languages', // Where to save the translation files.
packageName: 'WPGULP', // Package name.
bugReport: 'https://AhmadAwais.com/contact/', // Where can users report bugs.
lastTranslator: 'Ahmad Awais <your_email@email.com>', // Last translator Email ID.
team: 'AhmadAwais <your_email@email.com>', // Team's Email ID.

// Browsers you care about for autoprefixing. Browserlist https://github.com/ai/browserslist
// The following list is set as per WordPress requirements. Though, Feel free to change.
BROWSERS_LIST: [
    'last 2 version',
    '> 1%',
    'ie >= 11',
    'last 1 Android versions',
    'last 1 ChromeAndroid versions',
    'last 2 Chrome versions',
    'last 2 Firefox versions',
    'last 2 Safari versions',
    'last 2 iOS versions',
    'last 2 Edge versions',
    'last 2 Opera versions'
]
```

};

Here's what my gulpfile.babel.js file looks like:

```
    /**
 * Gulpfile.
 *
 * Gulp with WordPress.
 *
 * Implements:
 *      1. Live reloads browser with BrowserSync.
 *      2. CSS: Sass to CSS conversion, error catching, Autoprefixing, Sourcemaps,
 *         CSS minification, and Merge Media Queries.
 *      3. JS: Concatenates & uglifies Vendor and Custom JS files.
 *      4. Images: Minifies PNG, JPEG, GIF and SVG images.
 *      5. Watches files for changes in CSS or JS.
 *      6. Watches files for changes in PHP.
 *      7. Corrects the line endings.
 *      8. InjectCSS instead of browser page reload.
 *      9. Generates .pot file for i18n and l10n.
 *
 * @tutorial https://github.com/ahmadawais/WPGulp
 * @author Ahmad Awais <https://twitter.com/MrAhmadAwais/>
 */

/**
 * Load WPGulp Configuration.
 *
 * TODO: Customize your project in the wpgulp.js file.
 */
const config = require( './wpgulp.config.js' );

/**
 * Load Plugins.
 *
 * Load gulp plugins and passing them semantic names.
 */
const gulp = require( 'gulp' ); // Gulp of-course.

// CSS related plugins.
const sass = require( 'gulp-sass' ); // Gulp plugin for Sass compilation.
const minifycss = require( 'gulp-uglifycss' ); // Minifies CSS files.
const autoprefixer = require( 'gulp-autoprefixer' ); // Autoprefixing magic.
const postcss = require( 'gulp-postcss' ); // Uses Postcss

// JS related plugins.
const concat = require( 'gulp-concat' ); // Concatenates JS files.
const uglify = require( 'gulp-uglify' ); // Minifies JS files.
const babel = require( 'gulp-babel' ); // Compiles ESNext to browser compatible JS.

// Image related plugins.
const imagemin = require( 'gulp-imagemin' ); // Minify PNG, JPEG, GIF and SVG images with imagemin.

// Utility related plugins.
const rename = require( 'gulp-rename' ); // Renames files E.g. style.css -> style.min.css.
const lineec = require( 'gulp-line-ending-corrector' ); // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems. Gulp Plugin for Line Ending Corrector (A utility that makes sure your files have consistent line endings).
const filter = require( 'gulp-filter' ); // Enables you to work on a subset of the original files by filtering them using a glob.
const sourcemaps = require( 'gulp-sourcemaps' ); // Maps code in a compressed file (E.g. style.css) back to it’s original position in a source file (E.g. structure.scss, which was later combined with other css files to generate style.css).
const notify = require( 'gulp-notify' ); // Sends message notification to you.
const browserSync = require( 'browser-sync' ).create(); // Reloads browser and injects CSS. Time-saving synchronized browser testing.
const wpPot = require( 'gulp-wp-pot' ); // For generating the .pot file.
const sort = require( 'gulp-sort' ); // Recommended to prevent unnecessary changes in pot-file.
const cache = require( 'gulp-cache' ); // Cache files in stream for later use.
const remember = require( 'gulp-remember' ); //  Adds all the files it has ever seen back into the stream.
const plumber = require( 'gulp-plumber' ); // Prevent pipe breaking caused by errors from gulp plugins.
const beep = require( 'beepbeep' );

/**
 * Custom Error Handler.
 *
 * @param Mixed err
 */
const errorHandler = r => {
    notify.onError( '\n\n❌  ===> ERROR: <%= error.message %>\n' )( r );
    beep();

    // this.emit('end');
};

/**
 * Task: `browser-sync`.
 *
 * Live Reloads, CSS injections, Localhost tunneling.
 * @link http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/
 *
 * @param {Mixed} done Done.
 */
const browsersync = done => {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: config.projectURL,
        open: config.browserAutoOpen,
        injectChanges: config.injectChanges,
        watchEvents: [ 'change', 'add', 'unlink', 'addDir', 'unlinkDir' ]
    });
    done();
};

// Helper function to allow browser reload with Gulp 4.
const reload = done => {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
};

/**
 * Task: `styles`.
 *
 * Compiles Sass, Autoprefixes it and Minifies CSS.
 *
 * This task does the following:
 *    1. Gets the source scss file
 *    2. Compiles Sass to CSS
 *    3. Writes Sourcemaps for it
 *    4. Autoprefixes it and generates style.css
 *    5. Renames the CSS file with suffix .min.css
 *    6. Minifies the CSS file and generates style.min.css
 *    7. Injects CSS or reloads the browser via browserSync
 */
gulp.task( 'styles', () => {
    var tailwindcss = require( 'tailwindcss' );
    return gulp
        .src( config.styleSRC, { allowEmpty: true })
        .pipe( plumber( errorHandler ) )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe(
            sass({
                errLogToConsole: config.errLogToConsole,
                outputStyle: config.outputStyle,
                precision: config.precision
            })
        )
        .on( 'error', sass.logError )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write({ includeContent: false }) )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( config.BROWSERS_LIST ) )
        .pipe(postcss([
            tailwindcss('./tailwind.js'),
        ]))
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write( './' ) )
        .pipe( lineec() ) // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems.
        .pipe( gulp.dest( config.styleDestination ) )
        .pipe( filter( '**/*.css' ) ) // Filtering stream to only css files.
        .pipe( browserSync.stream() ) // Reloads style.css if that is enqueued.
        .pipe( rename({ suffix: '.min' }) )
        .pipe( minifycss({ maxLineLen: 10 }) )
        .pipe( lineec() ) // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems.
        .pipe( gulp.dest( config.styleDestination ) )
        .pipe( filter( '**/*.css' ) ) // Filtering stream to only css files.
        .pipe( browserSync.stream() ) // Reloads style.min.css if that is enqueued.
        .pipe( notify({ message: '\n\n✅  ===> STYLES — completed!\n', onLast: true }) );
});

/**
 * Task: `vendorsJS`.
 *
 * Concatenate and uglify vendor JS scripts.
 *
 * This task does the following:
 *     1. Gets the source folder for JS vendor files
 *     2. Concatenates all the files and generates vendors.js
 *     3. Renames the JS file with suffix .min.js
 *     4. Uglifes/Minifies the JS file and generates vendors.min.js
 */
gulp.task( 'vendorsJS', () => {
    return gulp
        .src( config.jsVendorSRC, { since: gulp.lastRun( 'vendorsJS' ) }) // Only run on changed files.
        .pipe( plumber( errorHandler ) )
        .pipe(
            babel({
                presets: [
                    [
                        '@babel/preset-env', // Preset to compile your modern JS to ES5.
                        {
                            targets: { browsers: config.BROWSERS_LIST } // Target browser list to support.
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            })
        )
        .pipe( remember( config.jsVendorSRC ) ) // Bring all files back to stream.
        .pipe( concat( config.jsVendorFile + '.js' ) )
        .pipe( lineec() ) // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems.
        .pipe( gulp.dest( config.jsVendorDestination ) )
        .pipe(
            rename({
                basename: config.jsVendorFile,
                suffix: '.min'
            })
        )
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( lineec() ) // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems.
        .pipe( gulp.dest( config.jsVendorDestination ) )
        .pipe( notify({ message: '\n\n✅  ===> VENDOR JS — completed!\n', onLast: true }) );
});

/**
 * Task: `customJS`.
 *
 * Concatenate and uglify custom JS scripts.
 *
 * This task does the following:
 *     1. Gets the source folder for JS custom files
 *     2. Concatenates all the files and generates custom.js
 *     3. Renames the JS file with suffix .min.js
 *     4. Uglifes/Minifies the JS file and generates custom.min.js
 */
gulp.task( 'customJS', () => {
    return gulp
        .src( config.jsCustomSRC, { since: gulp.lastRun( 'customJS' ) }) // Only run on changed files.
        .pipe( plumber( errorHandler ) )
        .pipe(
            babel({
                presets: [
                    [
                        '@babel/preset-env', // Preset to compile your modern JS to ES5.
                        {
                            targets: { browsers: config.BROWSERS_LIST } // Target browser list to support.
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            })
        )
        .pipe( remember( config.jsCustomSRC ) ) // Bring all files back to stream.
        .pipe( concat( config.jsCustomFile + '.js' ) )
        .pipe( lineec() ) // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems.
        .pipe( gulp.dest( config.jsCustomDestination ) )
        .pipe(
            rename({
                basename: config.jsCustomFile,
                suffix: '.min'
            })
        )
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( lineec() ) // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems.
        .pipe( gulp.dest( config.jsCustomDestination ) )
        .pipe( notify({ message: '\n\n✅  ===> CUSTOM JS — completed!\n', onLast: true }) );
});

/**
 * Task: `images`.
 *
 * Minifies PNG, JPEG, GIF and SVG images.
 *
 * This task does the following:
 *     1. Gets the source of images raw folder
 *     2. Minifies PNG, JPEG, GIF and SVG images
 *     3. Generates and saves the optimized images
 *
 * This task will run only once, if you want to run it
 * again, do it with the command `gulp images`.
 *
 * Read the following to change these options.
 * @link https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin
 */
gulp.task( 'images', () => {
    return gulp
        .src( config.imgSRC )
        .pipe(
            cache(
                imagemin([
                    imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: true }),
                    imagemin.jpegtran({ progressive: true }),
                    imagemin.optipng({ optimizationLevel: 3 }), // 0-7 low-high.
                    imagemin.svgo({
                        plugins: [ { removeViewBox: true }, { cleanupIDs: false } ]
                    })
                ])
            )
        )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( config.imgDST ) )
        .pipe( notify({ message: '\n\n✅  ===> IMAGES — completed!\n', onLast: true }) );
});

/**
 * Task: `clear-images-cache`.
 *
 * Deletes the images cache. By running the next "images" task,
 * each image will be regenerated.
 */
gulp.task( 'clearCache', function( done ) {
    return cache.clearAll( done );
});

/**
 * WP POT Translation File Generator.
 *
 * This task does the following:
 * 1. Gets the source of all the PHP files
 * 2. Sort files in stream by path or any custom sort comparator
 * 3. Applies wpPot with the variable set at the top of this file
 * 4. Generate a .pot file of i18n that can be used for l10n to build .mo file
 */
gulp.task( 'translate', () => {
    return gulp
        .src( config.watchPhp )
        .pipe( sort() )
        .pipe(
            wpPot({
                domain: config.textDomain,
                package: config.packageName,
                bugReport: config.bugReport,
                lastTranslator: config.lastTranslator,
                team: config.team
            })
        )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( config.translationDestination + '/' + config.translationFile ) )
        .pipe( notify({ message: '\n\n✅  ===> TRANSLATE — completed!\n', onLast: true }) );
});

/**
 * Watch Tasks.
 *
 * Watches for file changes and runs specific tasks.
 */
gulp.task(
    'default',
    gulp.parallel( 'styles', 'vendorsJS', 'customJS', 'images', browsersync, () => {
        gulp.watch( config.watchPhp, reload ); // Reload on PHP file changes.
        gulp.watch( config.watchStyles, gulp.series( 'styles' ) ); // Reload on SCSS file changes.
        gulp.watch( config.watchJsVendor, gulp.series( 'vendorsJS', reload ) ); // Reload on vendorsJS file changes.
        gulp.watch( config.watchJsCustom, gulp.series( 'customJS', reload ) ); // Reload on customJS file changes.
        gulp.watch( config.imgSRC, gulp.series( 'images', reload ) ); // Reload on customJS file changes.
    })
);
```

Is there something I'm not seeing in the Gulp files that I need to adjust?

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure, could it be this line `watchStyles: './assets/sass/*` that needs to be `watchStyles: './assets/sass/**/*` ? (see the extra *)

Comment: @AmauryHanser Yes! That seemed to fix the compiling issue. Thanks for suggesting that.

Now I need to fix the browser-sync issue.